# Force needed to move object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

just wondering if this makes sense.

If object 1 is stationary and has a mass of 500kg, and I hit it with object 2 which has a mass of 1000kg is there a way to find the minimum force needed to move object 1? (Neglect friction)

Secondly, If the force is applied instantly is there a way to determine the speed needed to move object 1? Can the force be related to a speed?

If the speed of object 1 is known after impact, is it the same as the speed of object 2 after impact and therefore the momentum exchange can be used to determine object 2 pre impact speed?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: *"Neglect friction"* Neglecting forces that prevent it *any* force will move any object. The only question is what change in velocity do you expect and that is answered by Newton's 2nd law.

Comment: If object 1 is at the top of a cliff when it’s impacted by object 2, so only gravitational force

Answer (score 0):

Step one of any physics problem is to draw a crappy picture in MS paint diagramming the forces acting on each object. Thus,

[image]

Now, we know that $\Sigma F = M*a$. Object 1, which is at rest, has an acceleration of 0. Since 0*500=0, it has no *net force* acting on it. That is to say, every force acting on object 1 has a counterforce acting on it in the opposite direction.

Now, let's analyze object 2. It's moving at a velocity of $V_0$ towards object 1. Since it isn't accelerating, there's no net force on the object. This basically sums up the free body diagram.

The center of the diagram shows the collision between the two objects. Collisions are defined by two pretty simple rules:

$$\Sigma p_i=\Sigma p_f$$
$$\Sigma E_i = \Sigma e_f$$

These rules are known as conservation of momentum and energy, respectively. However, they're not very useful in their current forms. We should expand them to fit our needs. I'll assume a perfectly [elastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) for this one. Basically, momentum is solved as $p=mv$, and kinetic energy is solved as $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2.

Now, a few things to note about your question:

1. Since you're operating on a frictionless surface in one dimension, *any* force exerted on object 1 will move it.
2. Force isn't actually related to speed. It's related to *change* in speed. You're actually moving at a few hundred thousand meters per second right now, believe it or not. And yet you're not feeling any force being applied on you.<sup>1</sup>

### TL;DR

Simply put:

1. Minimum force is anything above 0.
2. Speed necessary is anything above 0.

   - Force is defined as $m*a$ and is not related to speed
   - Force can't be applied instantly, as acceleration is $\Delta v/\Delta t$ and setting $\Delta t$ to zero makes things break.
3. Speed after impact is not the same.

   - It can be used to determine the pre- and post-impact speeds of both objects.

### Footnotes

1: er... you don't *feel* it, but there's some angular forces at work keeping the Earth around the sun and keeping you on the Earth.

Comment: I upvoted for the effort you put in; however I think this is an excessively complicated answer to a question that had important fundamental misconceptions.

Comment: Yeah, I actually rewrote it like five times trying to pare it down for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for your diagram, it looks pretty good even in word. And for the length of time you took to answer. I think I may have made a mistake when i said neglect friction. If object 1 is resting on a level surface and hit by object 2 and travels a distance is it then possible to determine pre impact speeds of object 2. For example a cannon ball hits a stone wall and the wall travels a known distance?

Comment: Yeah, just use 2D kinematics.